# Flutter cloud notifications are silent until manually toggled in app settings

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have set up my flutter application to receive notifications from cloud functions and set the parameters as can be seen below, however, the notifications are silent, until I go to my phone notification settings, and change my app's notification settings from 'Alert' to 'Silent' and then back to 'Alert'. Then the notifications start making sounds again. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Note that I'm having this issue with Android 11. I have another phone with Android 8.1 and that's working fine.

This is the config in my cloud function

```
const androidConfig = {
    priority: "high",
    notification: {
        defaultVibrateTimings: true,
        sound: "default",
        priority: "max",
        channelId: "high_importance_channel",
    },
};
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const androidConfig = {
    priority: "high",
    notification: {
        defaultVibrateTimings: true,
        sound: "default",
        priority: "max",
        channel: "high_importance_channel",
    },
};
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the code in the answer and the code in the question? It looks to be the same to me.